# SQL groupby on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a group-by in two columns, and coming from the NoSQL background, I'm used to it using Mongo's $group aggregation operator. But SQL doesn't have a straight-forward way to do it.

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: share your query or code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes It's possible
There are many samples available just google it for more details

```
SELECT CustomerGroup, Country FROM Customers GROUP BY Country,CustomerGroup
```

Like this

```
GROUP BY x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

**Group By clause:**

```
select col1,col2...col N from Table group by col1,col2,col3.....coln N
```

so here you can apply group by clause by N number of columns.

**How Its works when more than one columns exist in the group by clause?**

When you mention more than one column then SQL engine applies grouping from left-> right

**For Example**

```
Col1  |  Col2  | Col3

1         A        X
1         A        Y
2         A        P
2         A        P
2         A        P
```

After group by :

```
Col1  |  Col2  | Col3
1         A        X
1         A        Y
2         A        P
```